# Installed ffmpeg inside docker container, how can I compile c++ program?

Tags: c++, docker, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run a c++ program inside my docker container.
I've succeeded to install FFmpeg in the container (3 days of trying!).

But I Can't use it inside my c++ program, my c++ is calling packages which are part of ffmpeg like :

> libavcodec/avcodec.h

I know I'm missing something to connect between the installed ffmpeg and the c++ program, but I can't even understand where the ffmpeg is installed.

As you can see I'm pretty lost here, your help will help me a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to install ffmpeg development package

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by "can't use it"? The code cannot be compiled or linked inside container?

Comment: @ oguzismail - really I didn't know there is such thing...
@ halfelf - The code can't be compiled,when I'm trying to inlude libraries like: libavcodec/avcodec.h -> he's yelling that he doesn't have such libraries..
I know I'm missing something, but I can't solve it..

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: This question may be useful https://askubuntu.com/questions/766606/where-are-the-headers-of-libavcodec-and-libavformat-located

Comment: Thanks, But it's not there, probably it's different using docker container.